# Keep a flat array as a reference copy to a 2D or 3D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I have an array of point objects with x and y parameters such as :

```
this.points = [p1, p2, p3,..];
```

Which I flatten as a 1D array like so :

```
this.coords = [];
for(let p of this.points){
 this.coords.push(p.x);
 this.coords.push(p.y);
}
```

The coords array is now :

```
this.coords = [p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, ...]
```

My question is the following, I would like the modifications of either one of the arrays affect the other. Because right now when I make a modification to either `this.coords` or `this.points`, the other one isn't updated.

Is there a way of doing this, or am I thinking about this wrong and there is a general guideline to coding coordinates that I do not know of yes ?

Thanks

Comment: It seems a bit strange to me that you would need an array for the points and then one for the coordinates, could you show some example code of what you are doing with `coords` and `points` afterwards? In any case, I think using the `points` array for everything seems better, and if you really need the coordinates arranged in that order, you can create a helper function to get it.

Comment: the code is a little long and involves libraries, but put very simply, the coordinates are used and updated by different objects, such as a physics class that moves the points and a mesh class that creates new points and moves some. Until now I could just do with sharing the original array of points, but now some libraries require the points data to be flattened, and others don't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has two kinds of values: reference values and primitive values.

Primitive values, like numbers, are copied and editing the copy never influences the original and the other way around.
Because your x and y coordinates are probably primitive numerical values, this is not possible.

You could encapsulate them in reference values, for example using arrays with 1 element.

```js
const points = [{x: [1], y: [2]}, {x: [3], y:[4]}];
const flat = [points[0].x,points[0].y,points[1].x,points[1].y];
flat[0][0]+=9;
console.log(points[0].x)
```

But the question is why you want to do that in the first place.
If that is some kind of extreme cache optimization, like making your own commercial game engine, any kind of method to synchronize the two data structures will probably more than neutralize that optimization benefit.

Comment: So from what I'm understanding, is that creating a common structure of points for different libraries who require my list of points to be in different formats, will likely neutralize these libraries performances ? If that is the case then what is done generally to make everything compatible ?

Comment: As one object that handles my list of points handles physics, and the other handles mesh structure, I am closer to a Game Engine than I'd admit to myself, so am very interested in any kind of optimizeable workaround

Comment: @Kaspie: That kind of optimization is more common in C/C++ because JavaScript isn't well suited for high performance code anyways (e.g. extremely poor multithreading). Also, that kind of optimization, if done at all, is better done at a later point when you can clearly see there is a bottleneck at a specific place in the code.